# How to put a "comma" in a column header with grid.table

Tags: r, grid

I can't get the "comma" between L_i-1 and Li.

I put the comma, but it does not appear.

I attach an image of how it appears and the code.

```
colnames (tablasolucion1) <-lapply(list( "paste(L[i-1], L[i] )" ,  'paste(Aspirantes ~ (n[i]))', "paste(Amplitud ~ (c[i]))", "paste(Densidad ~ (d[i]))" ),glue)
tt <- ttheme_default(colhead=list(fg_params = list(parse=TRUE)))
grid.newpage()
grid.table(tablasolucion1, rows = NULL, theme=tt)
```

[image]

[image]

```
colnames (tablasolucion1) <-lapply(list( "paste(Puntuación ~ (list(L[i-1], L[i])))" ,glue)
```

Comment: Perhaps: "paste(L[i-1], ",", L[i] )"

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. But according to `?plotmath`, if you want a comma list, use `"list(L[i-1], L[i] )"`

Comment: Perfect.
Above is the image and the code.